# Get a object ID from another class in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Why i get an error on this one? I want the ID of genre... In the Database the game table have a foreign key of genre_id thats in the table of genre.

```
 public List<Game> GetGames()
    {
        List<Game> games = new List<Game>();
        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            string selectQuery = "select * from game";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, conn);
            MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                string gameNaam = dataReader.GetString("gamenaam");
                int gameId = dataReader.GetInt32("game_id");
                int genreId = dataReader.GetInt32("genre_id");
                Game game = new Game { ID = genreId, game.Genre.ID = genreId, Naam = gameNaam};

                games.Add(game);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write("Ophalen van genres mislukt " + e);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

        return games;
    }
}
```

I get a error on this one -----> game.Genre.ID = genreId

code genre and game:

```
   public class Game 
{
    public String Naam { get; set; }

    public Genre Genre { get; set; }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0} (id = {1})", Naam, ID);
    }
}
```

---

```
 public class Genre
{
    public string Naam { get; set; }
    public bool Verslavend { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public override String ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0} ({1})", Naam,
            Verslavend ? "Verslavend" : "Niet verslavend");
    }

  }
```

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0165 Use of unassigned local variable 'game' WorkshopCSharp(II)Start C:\Users\tonyv\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WorkshopCSharp(II)Start\DatabaseControllers\GameController.cs 180 Active

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0747 Invalid initializer member declarator WorkshopCSharp(II)Start C:\Users\tonyv\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WorkshopCSharp(II)Start\DatabaseControllers\GameController.cs 180 Active

Comment: The only thing i want is the genre_id from the table game

Comment: Right, because you're trying to use `game` here: `game.Genre.ID = genreId` in a an object initializer for `game` itself. You probably wanted `Genre = new Genre { Id = genreId }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is invalid syntax:

```
new Game { ID = genreId, game.Genre.ID = genreId, Naam = gameNaam};
                         ^--- here
```

`game` doesn't exist in that context.  Nor can you set sub-properties in a property initializer like that.

If you want to set the `Genre` property, you have to set it on its own.  Something like this:

```
new Game {
  ID = genreId,
  Genre = new Genre {
    ID = genreId
  },
  Naam = gameNaam
};
```